# Trying to make Quartz job listener dynamically

Tags: java, generics, quartz-scheduler, quartz-core

I've seen several posts about this, however don't work with the new JobListener builder approach in Quartz.

I'm trying to create a JobListener dynamically, using a string that stores the listener class name. However I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
The method addJobListener(JobListener, Matcher<JobKey>) in the type ListenerManager is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#4-of ? extends JobListener>, KeyMatcher<JobKey>)
```

Here is a code snippet

```
public class SchedulerTriggerListener<T> {

    private T objReff = null;

    public SchedulerTriggerListener(T param){
        this.objReff = param;
    }

    public T getObjReff(){
        return this.objReff;
    }


    public void printData() throws SchedulerException{
        String s = "ClassName";
        Class<?> listenerClass = null;
        listenerClass = Class.forName (s);
        JobKey jobKey = new JobKey("dummyJobName", "group1");
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(
                (Class<? extends JobListener>)listenerClass, KeyMatcher.keyEquals(jobKey)
        );
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: which quartz version are you using?

Comment: did you try to cast to JobListener instead of Class<? extends JobListener>?

Comment: quartz version is 2.2.1. you mean 

scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(
       (JobListener>)listenerClass, KeyMatcher.keyEquals(jobKey)
     );